# Speedometer Chart

Tags: gauge, needle

Can imagecharts draw a speedometer chart like the one in the image, where the shape and colors of each segment of the gauge are always the same and the only thing that changes is the position of the needle?
[See Needle Gauge Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAUxf.png)

If the answer is no, can you please direct me to a service that is able to generate such a chart through a URL address?

Comment: Haven't found anything that's being able to be rendered through URL's, but have found this: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/php/your-first-gauge-using-php Maybe it's helpfull